# Using c# to fill a variable with a LINQ any match

Tags: c#, linq

I've found this nifty function:

```
stringArray.Any(stringToCheck.Contains)
```

which gives a true if the `stringToCheck` contains any of the strings in the `stringArray`

what I want to do then is fill a variable with the string it actually matched - is is possible to extend this linq query to pull out the matched string?

All I can think of is to cycle through the array and if there's a match then move it in to the variable - but if I'm doing it that way then I might as well just skip the oneliner function... I'm not really sure if this is possible,  so many other options so dunno where to start...

```
public class tester
{
    private string[] stringArray = { "XX", "YY", "ZZ" };
    private string stringToCheck = "12-YY-34";
    private string arrayMatch;
}
```

I want to attribute "YY" to arrayMatch because the stringToCheck contains "YY" which can be found in the stringArray;

Comment: There is FirstOrDefault for this

Comment: Are you looking for linq `where` and `select`? Could you provide some code or sample string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `stringArray.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck.Contains)`.
It gives you `null` if the string was not found, else returns the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try something more like:

```
    var stringArray = new string[3]{"XX", "YY", "ZZ"};
    var stringToCheck = "12-YY-34";

    Console.WriteLine(stringArray.FirstOrDefault(i=>stringToCheck.Contains(i)));
```

returns:
     YY

Comment: my bad - I read the question too quickly. Updated. And FWIW, I actually prefer the Lambda syntax as it generally matches more closely the other LINQ queries I have in my methods. Yes, it's a bit more verbose, but I actually find it more legible. "Contains what? Oh, contains 'i'"

Comment: Fair enough. I think it's natural to tend toward conciseness when working with lambdas but what doesn't hold water is the argument that `i`, or other meaningless names like `a`, `b`, and so on, is somehow providing useful information; they don't so they're sort of worthless. Particularly in this case where we're calling `FirstOrDefault` on a `stringArray` and `Contains` on the `stringToCheck`. Pretty darn clear without the `i=>...(i)` part. But opinions...we all have them.